# What is Parallelism(Distribute Streams) in Execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

What is `Parallelism(Distribute Streams)` operation in `Execution plan`. Why it is increasing the rows count from the previous operation.

**Query :**

```
SELECT TOP 5000 MM.MEMBER_ID,
                MM.MEMBER_NO,
                MM.MEMBER_NAME,
                MM.TRADE_CLASS,
                MT.DESCRIPTION,
                MS.DESCRIPTION,
                MAI.ADDRESS_1,
                MAI.ADDRESS_2,
                MAI.CITY,
                MAI.STATE,
                MAI.ZIP
FROM   MEMBER_MASTER MM
       INNER JOIN MEMBER_TYPE MT
               ON MT.CODE = MM.MEMBER_TYPE
       INNER JOIN MEMBER_STATUS MS
               ON MS.CODE = MM.MEMBER_STATUS
       INNER JOIN MEMBER_ADDRESS_INFO MAI
               ON MM.MEMBER_ID = MAI.MEMBER_ID
WHERE  MAI.PRIMARY_ADDRESS_FLAG = 'YES'
```

**Execution Plan:**

[image]

From the above execution plan you can clearly see that the rows count is increased from **39,771** to **1,272,672**. Why is it happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The system has decided that it can benefit from performing some of the processing in parallel. In this case, it's apparently decided to let 32 independent threads work with the set of rows (1272672 = 39771*32). It shouldn't be a cause for concern - generally - and the "duplicate" rows will be eliminated by the later `(Gather Streams)` operation.

Comment: Will it cause any performance issues. Also which `operation`(Join etc..) is causing the execution planner to use `Parallelism(Distribute Streams)`

Comment: @Fireblade - it *shouldn't* cause an issue - but note I'm being quite cagey. The optimizer has, historically, sometimes parallelized operations that would have been quicker as serial processes, or with less parallelism. That's why there's a [query hint called `MAXDOP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) for if you need to force the optimizer to abandon parallel plans. Don't touch it though unless you've demonstrated a performance *problem*. Parallelism is being used multiple times in the plan to *support* the join operations.